# Best configuration management software for azure

Tags: azure

I would like to know which is the best online configuration management software for the Windows Azure cloud environment. I would like to install a SCM tool on the cloud account which can be accessed using a client app by developers.

Regards,

Salman.

Comment: I recommend Microsoft TFS. It integrates with Azure well. If you want sth. smaller, take a look at Dynamsoft SCM Anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Azure now has GIT support, you should try that. It allows you to directly publish from GIT. Also, TFS is a good option, you can check tfspreview.com it also integrates well with Azure and you can directly publish from there.

Answer (score 0):

What features are you looking for? Quest makes some nice tools for Windows Azure.  Depending on what you want, other vendors like Cerebrata, Opstera, or Paraleap's AzureWatch may be good options too.

Comment: It would basically be for teamwork on the codebase and revision control. What I would also like to know is that, if the codebase resides on the server, then how do we package the build for deployment? Will that still be done from Visual Studio?

Comment: Are these tools still available? I tried downloading Spotlight (R) for Azure but couldn't find it anywere! The Official Quest website for Azure Tools has turned into a forum. Got any idea?